# How to override focus background style for a div element in firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

I have set the tabindex of a div element to -1 to allow focus.  Firefox highlights the div element when it gets focus with a gray background.  How do remove this default behavior?

```
*:focus {
  -moz-appearance:none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: none; 
}
```

has no effect.

The firefox version is 38.3.

Here is screen clipping of the rendering of the elements:
[image]

Comment: can you provide screenshot

Comment: ...and your firefox version too.

Comment: Right click over the div element and select "Inspect Element" to get feedback from the Firefox browser on the CSS attributes being applied to this element. That feedback may answer your question.

Comment: Inspecting the element show the background color set to transparent.  If I set the background-color of all element to say green, When the element obtains focus, the gray background overrides the green background.  Is there a different attribute besides background that sets the hover background style?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') > -1){
    $('.myDiv').css('background-color','yellow');
    }
 });
```

```css
.myDiv{
  background-color : green;
 }
```

```html
<script
   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 </script>
 <div class="myDiv">
  <h1>Change Background Color in Mozila</h1>
 </div>
```

Comment: Try this jQuery code, if you not strict to CSS. The above code is example where you change the HTML behavior specific to your Requirement

Comment: I am not using jquery and need a css only solution.